# how to make the player in unity to scale y axis down when pressed and y axis up when released using c#

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am using unity to ,make a game through c# and i want to ask if how to make the player scale y_axis down when pressing a key on PC and scaling y_axis up when the key is released.

using System;
    using UnityEngine;

```
public class Playermovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float forwardforce = 2000f;
    public float sideswaysforce = 500f;
    Vector3 small;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardforce * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetKey("d"))
        {

            rb.AddForce(sideswaysforce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {

            rb.AddForce(-sideswaysforce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey("f"))
        {
            small = transform.localScale;

            small.y = 0.5f;

            transform.localScale = small;
        }

    }



}

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, in your current code you could continuously shrink the scale and nothing resets it.

```
public Vector3 halfScale;
public Vector3 originalScale;

void Start() {
originalScale = transform.localScale;
halfScale = originalScale;
halfScale.y = halfScale.y * 0.5f;
}

        //...in your fixedupdate loop
        if(Input.GetKey("f"))
        {
        transform.localScale = halfScale;
        } else {
        transform.localScale = originalScale;
        }
```

Comment: but this wont make the player go up when i release the f key, it will only shrink it